# Python pandas framework - List object to CSV conversion

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am new to python scripting. I am using python 3.8.5 and pandas framework to write a list object in to CSV.  Below is the sample code attempted to convert list to csv

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
list=['red','blue','green','violet','orange','yellow','white','black','purple']
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Dhinesh\\result.csv", index = False)
```

### Expected output

expected output is to write the list objects in a CSV with one list object per cell and 3 objects in row(3x3 table).

The actual output I get lists down all the list objects in a single column one below the other.

### Question

How do we loop through the list objects to mention the line termination(or) column size and write in a new line so that I get a 3x3 output with one list object in each cell?

Comment: Just as good hygiene, don't call a variable with a name of a class... in your code, this means that the variable `list` should be different as that word is the identifier of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correclty understand,  given the list `l` first You need to reshape the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
l = ['red','blue','green','violet','orange','yellow','white','black','purple','gray']
l = l + (3 - len(l) % 3) * [pd.NA]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(l).reshape(-1,3))
```

result:

```
        0       1       2
0     red    blue   green
1  violet  orange  yellow
2   white   black  purple
3    gray    <NA>    <NA>
```

If the list has number of elements which is not multiplication o 3, I add `(3 - len(l) % 3)` empty elements `<NA>` to fix shape of resulting array.

Then save the dataframe `df` as normal.

Comment: Is 'np' from pandas module or a different module? I get the below error on try to reshape 
NameError: name 'np' is not defined.

Comment: Sorry for not complete code, now I've added necessary imports

Comment: Thanks!! that helps me partially. But, what in case we have uneven number of objects in list.  Say we have 8 or 10 objects. reshape(3,-1) throws an error. Is it possible to have the last cell empty\written to next row respectively.

Comment: I've found the solution - look the answer please